# How to config bash history search to be interactive?

Tags: bash

I get the following interactive prompt (navigatable using <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>)when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> using bash. What is this plugin/configuration? I'd like to install this on my other servers. Tried to search on google to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Best place to check for this sort of thing is in the typical profile locations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629304/locate-my-bash-configuration-file though that left out `/etc/profile.d`

Comment: You are correct, got some new hints in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Turns out none of the hints helped

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That behavior is part of the command `fzf`. You can follow this guide: [fzf - command line fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)  to install it on your operating system.
In my case (once installed) I had to source these files:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf-key-bindings
```

In other cases might source the files from a different path:

```
source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/completion.bash
source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.bash
```

If you want to avoid typing each time those commands you can add those lines to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo -e 'source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf\nsource /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf-key-bindings' >> ~/.bashrc

echo -e 'source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf\nsource /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf-key-bindings' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I found it here as well: `~/.bashrc | grep fzf`. It's easy once you know what you are looking for... I was trying to `bind -p | grep "\C-r"`, but apparently fzf bound the key in a way that `bind -p` doesnt show it.

Comment: Maybe it's different for binding with `\C-r`. If you see the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fzf-key-bindings` you will see something like this:
`bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'` ... 
I commented that line and reset my shell and the interactive history was not working.

Comment: I did the exact same thing, the line `bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'` is the magic line. But there is nothing related to `fzf` in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` for me.

Comment: @SidaZhou maybe your `fzf` files are under `/usr/share/doc/`. You can try: `sudo find /usr/share -iname '*fzf*'` for getting the paths which might have the `fzf` files.